# Android UI, Networking and async code

Tags: android, multithreading, networking

I have a serious problem which I can't a solution to.
I need to authenticate a token in order to let the user login into my app, the problem is that even though I'm using the AsyncTask, and probably because of it, I can't authenticate it in time. Other problem that sometimes accurs is that I get the NetworkOnMainThreadException error... I'm really hopeless.

Here's the flow -

```
Check for existsing token -> Validate -> Move to next activity
```

And here's my code -

```
    public boolean validateToken(TokenAccess token) {
    new IsValid().execute(token);
    return isValid;
}

private class IsValid extends AsyncTask<TokenAccess, Void, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(TokenAccess... params) {
        TokenAccess token = params[0];
        switch (token.getSource().getSource()) {
        case 'M':
            new UrlDownloader(new UrlDownloader.DownloadListener() {

                @Override
                public void setRequest(HttpRequest request) {}

                @Override
                public void onRecive(String content) {
                    if (content.contains("stats")) {
                        isValid = true;
                    } else {
                        isValid = false;
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Exception e) {}

            }, UrlDownloader.RequestType.GET)
                    .execute("https://api.meetup.com/dashboard?access_token="
                            + token.getToken());
        }
        return isValid;
    }

}
```

That's is the URLDownloader class -

```
public class UrlDownloader extends AsyncTask<String, Void, HttpResponse> {

    public static final String TAG = "net.ytsweb.socigo.assests.UrlDownloader";

    public enum RequestType {
        GET, POST;
    }

    private RequestType type;
    private DownloadListener listener;

    public UrlDownloader(DownloadListener listener, RequestType type) {
        this.type = type;
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    protected HttpResponse doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpUriRequest request;
        HttpResponse response;

        if (type == RequestType.GET) {
            request = new HttpGet(params[0]);
        } else {
            request = new HttpPost(params[1]);
        }
        listener.setRequest(request);
        try {
             response = httpClient.execute(request);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            listener.onError(e);
            return null;
        }

        return response;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(HttpResponse response) {
        try {
            Log.d(TAG, response.getAllHeaders()[0].getValue() + "");
            listener.onRecive(EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            listener.onError(e);
        }
    }

    public interface DownloadListener {
        public void onRecive(String content);
        public void onError(Exception e);
        public void setRequest(HttpRequest request);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [onPostExecute](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute%28Result%29) for handling the result of the `IsValid` `AsyncTask`. What I don't understand: why two AsyncTasks? One would be enough, do everything in there, and handle the result in the one and only `onPostExecute`.

Whatever happens in `doInBackground` is in a separate thread, `onPostExecute` happens on the UI-thread again. One `AsyncTask` is enough, but don't fetch a result in your `validateToken` method. In there, just execute your `AsyncTask` and whatever you need to do with the result you have to initiate in the `onPostExecute`.

As a basic example of what I mean:

```
public boolean validateToken(TokenAccess token) {
  new YourAsyncTask().execute(token);
  // DON'T rely on a result here
}

public class YourAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<?, ?, ?> {

  @Override
  protected ? doInBackground(?) {
    // do networking in background-task

    return result;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(? response) {
    // handle result here.. call a method in your main class, a listener with the result, or start an Activity directly
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I've used another async task because I've thought that the UI exception is because of it.

Comment: Forgot to mention, I've made some kind of a listener that has a function which runs onPostExecute, the onRecive function. But how can I return from there a boolean?

Comment: You don't "return" a boolean at all! Just execute an AsyncTask for your network operations, and depending on the result, show an error or start the new Activity from within your `onPostExecute` (or call a method/listener that does this from there). Don't depend on a return value from your `AsyncTask` when executing it.